# React Native Facebook auth with Firebase not working: unresolved promise (logInWithReadPermissionsAsync)

Tags: facebook, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement *Facebook Login* to my *React Native* (Expo) + *Firebase App*. However, `Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync` does not resolve - the app gets stuck on Facebook, and neither 'success' nor 'cancel' is returned.

The login flow looks like this and then gets stuck on the last screen (blank FB app with just "Cancel" button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDoZL.jpg)

Any ideas what I might be missing?

```
import firebase from './firebase'

export async function loginWithFacebook() {
    const { type, token } = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync('2197841940631405', { permissions: ['public_profile', 'email']});
    console.log(type);
    if (type == 'success') {
        const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: anything new on this ?

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing new. For now I've replaced FB login with Google login, and it works fine: `Google.logInAsync()`

Comment: The same issue with me.